# pandas groupby transform: multiple functions applied at the same time with custom names

Tags: pandas, multi-index, pandas-groupby

as the title suggests, I want to be able to do the following (best explained with some code) [`pandas 0.20.1` is mandatory]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 4), columns=[['a','a','b','b'], ['alfa','beta','alfa','beta',]])

def as_is(x):
    return x
def power_2(x):
    return x**2

# desired result

a.transform([as_is, power_2])
```

the problem is the function could be more complex than this and thus I would lose the "naming" feature as `pandas.DataFrame.transform` only allows for lists to be passed whereas a dictionary would have been most convenient.

going back to the basics, I got to this:

```
dict_funct= {'as_is': as_is, 'power_2': power_2}

def wrapper(x):
    return pd.concat({k: x.apply(v) for k,v in dict_funct.items()}, axis=1)

a.groupby(level=[0,1], axis=1).apply(wrapper)
```

but the output Dataframe is all `nan`, presumably due to `multi-index` columns ordering. is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "I would lose the "naming" feature"? You can always rename your new columns by changing the function names. Can you add an example to show what the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need `dict` I remove paramater `axis` in `concat` to to default (`axis=0`), but then is necessary add parameter `group_keys=False` and function [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
def wrapper(x):
    return pd.concat({k: x.apply(v) for k,v in dict_funct.items()})

a.groupby(level=[0,1], axis=1, group_keys=False).apply(wrapper).unstack(0)
```

Similar solution:

```
def wrapper(x):
    return pd.concat({k: x.transform(v) for k,v in dict_funct.items()})

a.groupby(level=[0,1], axis=1, group_keys=False).apply(wrapper).unstack(0)
```

---

Another solution is simply add `list comprehension`:

```
a.transform([v for k, v in dict_funct.items()])
```

Comment: never used the group_keys=False. a godsend. thank you!